# Compiling a library using Fay: hidden package 'base'

Tags: fay

I'm having trouble compiling a working Haskell library to JavaScript using Fay.

I believe I've successfully installed Fay using cabal-dev, and set the HASKELL_PACKAGE_SANDBOX environment.

When I attempt to compile, I get the following:

```
 C:\ror>cabal-dev\bin\fay --package fay-base --library --include src src\IRR.hs
 fay: ghc:
 src\Period.hs:27:8:
     Could not find module `Data.Function'
     It is a member of the hidden package `base'.
     Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Using `ghc-pkg list` I can see that `base-4.6.0.1` is exposed.

Any hints on what to try next?

Thanks!
N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to windows or cabal-dev.

When typechecking Fay passes `-hide-package base` to GHC, otherwise it would conflict with `fay-base`. Fay wouldn't be able to use the installed base either way, it needs the source files and base contains a lot of things that Fay doesn't support.

`fay-base` doesn't define `Data.Function`, the only reason is that the module hasn't been implemented (please send a PR if you add it!)

You don't need to compile with `--package fay-base` by the way, it's implicit.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that sounds like the issue.